# How to prettily format GPS data in java/android?

Tags: java, android, gps, location, string-formatting

I'm getting gps data as 2 `double` - one `double` for longitude, another `double` for lattitude.

I'm formatting them to `Strings` as

```
Location.convert(mGps.getLatitude(), Location.FORMAT_MINUTES);
```

However I want it to be formatted as they do on google maps saying, say, 17 (here's the symbol for degrees) 55 (here's the symbol for minutes) 23 (here's the symbol for seconds).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#Java_Implementation) you've got a Java implementation to do that conversion.

```
// Input a double latitude or longitude in the decimal format
// e.g. 87.728056
String decimalToDMS(double coord) {
    String output, degrees, minutes, seconds;

    // gets the modulus the coordinate divided by one (MOD1).
    // in other words gets all the numbers after the decimal point.
    // e.g. mod = 87.728056 % 1 == 0.728056
    //
    // next get the integer part of the coord. On other words the whole number part.
    // e.g. intPart = 87

    double mod = coord % 1;
    int intPart = (int)coord;

    //set degrees to the value of intPart
    //e.g. degrees = "87"

    degrees = String.valueOf(intPart);

    // next times the MOD1 of degrees by 60 so we can find the integer part for minutes.
    // get the MOD1 of the new coord to find the numbers after the decimal point.
    // e.g. coord = 0.728056 * 60 == 43.68336
    //      mod = 43.68336 % 1 == 0.68336
    //
    // next get the value of the integer part of the coord.
    // e.g. intPart = 43

    coord = mod * 60;
    mod = coord % 1;
    intPart = (int)coord;

    // set minutes to the value of intPart.
    // e.g. minutes = "43"
    minutes = String.valueOf(intPart);

    //do the same again for minutes
    //e.g. coord = 0.68336 * 60 == 41.0016
    //e.g. intPart = 41
    coord = mod * 60;
    intPart = (int)coord;

    // set seconds to the value of intPart.
    // e.g. seconds = "41"
    seconds = String.valueOf(intPart);

    // I used this format for android but you can change it 
    // to return in whatever format you like
    // e.g. output = "87/1,43/1,41/1"
    output = degrees + "/1," + minutes + "/1," + seconds + "/1";

    //Standard output of D°M′S″
    //output = degrees + "°" + minutes + "'" + seconds + "\"";

    return output;
}

   /*
    * Conversion DMS to decimal 
    *
    * Input: latitude or longitude in the DMS format ( example: N 43° 36' 15.894")
    * Return: latitude or longitude in decimal format   
    * hemisphereOUmeridien => {W,E,S,N}
    *
    */
    public double DMSToDecimal(String hemisphereOUmeridien,double degres,double minutes,double secondes)
    {
            double LatOrLon=0;
            double signe=1.0;

            if((hemisphereOUmeridien=="W")||(hemisphereOUmeridien=="S")) {signe=-1.0;}              
            LatOrLon = signe*(Math.floor(degres) + Math.floor(minutes)/60.0 + secondes/3600.0);

            return(LatOrLon);               
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called a Degrees to DMS conversion.
see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213449
And java code and more info at [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion)

Comment: Ok, and are there some Java API to do that?

Comment: posted a link, its realy a few lines, so using that link, you write that yourself, easily.